# ngingx redirects me instead of pointing to site

Tags: nginx, subdomain, proxypass

I'm trying to get nginx to show a webpage running on port 8001 without changing the url to `xx.xx.xx.xx:8001`. with `xx.xx.xx.xx` being my server ip.

According to multiple sources, `proxy_set_header` should be able to handle that, but it doesn't. Instead it redirects me. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name aa.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8001;
    listen [::]:8001;

    server_name domain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/domain/static;
        autoindex off;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/domain/static/robots.txt;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```